# How can I escape from python environment hell?

Tags: python, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04

I don't know how I've gotten here but I have many competing installations of python on my Ubuntu 16.04 path. Some I use, some I don't.

[image: all the environments]

I'm at the point now where I want to clean up things to save headache when troubleshooting issues but I don't know any strategies or tools of tackling this.

What is the best way I can find out which environments are being used and not used?

How can I determine which python directories are being pointed to and which ones are abandoned?

Whats a quick way I can get a list of non-standard packages installed to each environment?

Comment: You can use the `sys.executable` constant to find the interpreter. You can use `python -m pip list` to find all extra installed packages

Comment: Those are good suggestions! And I found that `pip list | xargs -exec pip show` will provide the exact install locations of python packages.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can try

1. `which python` usually for python2.x and `which python3` for python3.x.
2. Then decide which version you want to use by default then you can use `export python='Your required python interpreter path'` for permanent changes, or you can use `alias python=PATH` for temporary usage.
3. Also see where the `pip` and `pip3` are pointing at by using `which pipX`. Thus you can use one of them to install required packages.

**I would recommend you to use *virtualenv* or *pipenv***  so that you get more fine grained control over the interpreter selection according to the need of your project.

**Note do not uninstall any of the above python packages without some research as there might be system dependencies thus breaking your system.**